# ionic ng-if Does not work with $index as index of scope in template view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have an issue with ng-if i have the next code :

```js
<ion-slide-box ng-if="sencillo.length && sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged(sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path)" class="fondo-rojo" show-pager="false" does-continue="true">
             
                <ion-slide on-swipe-right="setR({{sencillo}},$index)" on-swipe-left="setL({{sencillo}},$index)" ng-repeat="senci in sencillo"  repeat-done="repeatDone()">
                      
                           <h1 class="margen-slide slide-estilo">{{senci.title}}</h1>
                           <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:70px" >
                           <a ng-click="play(senci.custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="70px" height="70px"></a>
                           <!--<button ng-click="nextSlide()"> >> </button>-->
                           </div>
                </ion-slide>
              
            </ion-slide-box>
          
           
            <ion-slide-box ng-if="sencillo.length && !sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged('/android_asset/www/raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3')" class="fondo-rojo" show-pager="false" does-continue="true">
                <ion-slide on-swipe-right="setR({{sencillo}},$index)" on-swipe-left="setL({{sencillo}},$index)" ng-repeat="senci in sencillo"  repeat-done="repeatDone()">
                      
                           <h1 class="margen-slide slide-estilo">{{senci.title}}</h1>
                           <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:70px" >
                           <a ng-click="play('/android_asset/www/raw/'+senci.sound_title+'.mp3')"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="70px" height="70px"></a>
                           <!--<button ng-click="nextSlide()"> >> </button>-->
                           </div>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
```

I 'm trying to evaluate if sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path exists , then run the first slidebox else run the second slidebox. The problem is the ng-if always detect sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path as a null value so always the second slidebox is executed, however in another view this works fine, like this:

```js
<div ng-if="editsimpleRow.custom_sound_path">
                    <a ng-click="play(editsimpleRow.custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                    <!--<a ng-click="play(editsimple.custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>-->
                </div>
                <div ng-if="!editsimpleRow.custom_sound_path">
                    <a ng-click="play('/android_asset/www/raw/'+editsimpleRow.sound_title+'.mp3')"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
                </div>
```

i just see the $index value as the only difference, i will appreciate any help!!, thanks, sorry for my english.

Comment: `$index` comes from an `ng-repeat` directive or so. Could you please post what's around the code you have posted?

Comment: Yes, you can see in `<ion-slide>` there is a ng-repeat for `$scope sencillo`  `ng-repeat="senci in sencillo" `, the problem is that always `<ion-slide-box ng-if="sencillo.length && !sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path"` is executed, so i assume the `sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path` is null or empty for the `ng-if` directive, and obviously is not.

Comment: $index from ng-repeat is available inside of that element only, so in your ion-slide-box it is always undefined.

Comment: hi, i thought that but take a look on the code above `on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged('/android_asset/www/raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3')"` that works fine in another cases, so $index is available outside, at least for  `on-slide-changed`. that's why a tried this way, regards.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: yes for sure, it is 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i changed my view for :

```js
<ion-slide-box ng-if="sencillo.length" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged('/android_asset/www/raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3',sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path)" class="fondo-rojo" show-pager="false" does-continue="true">
                <ion-slide on-swipe-right="setR({{sencillo}},$index)" on-swipe-left="setL({{sencillo}},$index)" ng-repeat="senci in sencillo"  repeat-done="repeatDone()">
                      
                           <h1 class="margen-slide slide-estilo">{{senci.title}}</h1>
                           <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:70px" >
                           <a ng-click="slideHasChanged('/android_asset/www/raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3',sencillo[$index].custom_sound_path)"><img ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="70px" height="70px"></a>
                           <!--<button ng-click="nextSlide()"> >> </button>-->
                           </div>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
```

Then i put the if in my controller, like this:

```js
$scope.slideHasChanged = function(src,srcdos){
        
        if (srcdos == null){
            $scope.play(src);

        }else {
            $scope.play(srcdos);
        }
       
     }
```

note that the function slideHasChanged now get two parameters instead one.

Comment: Seems like you are doing it the difficult way, but I'm glad that you managed to make it working 

Comment: Hi Kate, well I needed to solve this problem to move forward, so i tried this and it works, regards, thanks for the comments.